# Why ELIFECYCLE error occurs while running npm start?

Tags: reactjs

I had created a new react project and while running it using npm start it shows me ELIFECYCLE error.

I had tried deleting the package.lock.json and node_modules and removed the dependencies and done a fresh npm install. Eventhough the same error occurs again.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "tables",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

C:\Users\Srinithi K\tables
this is my path where the react project called tables is present.

output after running npm start:

[image]

Comment: are you in the correct folder path? Maybe you are in a folder and your react-app is in a folder inside the folder you are in. But if you have been able to do a npm install maybe you are in the right path

Comment: Most of the time the error is above that. At least for me that is. ELIFECYCLE is just a node error saying that your applicatie stoped unexpectedly. Maybe post some more of the error log might help.

Comment: folder path is correct as npm can read package.json and get name and version. You need to scroll up to see the actual error as @Raoul suggested

Comment: 13 verbose stack Error: tables@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)         These are  log generated

Comment: Could you please update your question with the directory tree and `package.json`?
If possible, please create a web demo

Comment: Hmm that seems more like logs occur `after` the ELIFECYCLE message. Can you check what log messages occur `before` the ELIFECYCLE.

Comment: verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0                                                                                               These are the log before ELIFECYCLE

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to package-lock.json file. If you had not run eject, it might not have occurred. Installing the latest version of npm would help.
Try these fixes:
Go to your application directory in the command prompt,

1. rm -rf node-modules
2. npm install npm@latest -g
3. npm install

You might consider the following command if the above fix doesn't work.

- npm install react-scripts